# Дать возможность изменять высоту блока кода

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено

Бывает, к сообщениям пользователи добавляют достаточно объемный код и очень печалит отсутствие возможности ручного увеличения высоты блока кода, чтобы визуально охватить большую его часть и меньше крутить колесо. К примеру, добавляя новый ответ мы имеем возможность растянуть форму по вертикали, это удобно.

Вот здесь https://goo.gl/e6YvFt, к примеру, интуитивно так и просится потянуть "вьюху" с кодом за нижний край, чтобы увидеть больше, ан нет. Приходится крутить туда-сюда колесом.

Comment: Вроде пробегал userscript для такого.

Comment: Заголовок вопроса не совсем коррелирует с текстом. В тексте говорится о том, как менять размер блока по высоте - это при том, что автор сам знает, что можно колёсиком крутануть. Меня не напрягает, я прокручу. А вот в заголовке говорится о более общем запросе: менять размеры блока, что может восприниматься и как изменение ширины блока. И вот это уже интересно. См. тот же самый скриншот -- там и по горизонтали не уместился код. Только мешает сайдбар справа, только во всех формах с текстом (комментарий, ответ) можно лишь высоту регулировать. Печаль. ( В общем, предлагаю автору уточнить заголовок.

Comment: Кстати, я не понимаю вот чего: в чём принципиальная разница между тем, чтобы крутануть колёсико над кодом или начать долго целиться в нижний край, потом аккуратно тянуть его? Явно ведь второй вариант сложнее первого.

Comment: @AK вы большой кусок кода изучаете за один просмотр? В таком случае, я вам завидую. Я имею ввиду разницу между "крутануть колесо" и "крутить его туда-сюда" в течение пары минут. "Целиться в нижний край" - это уже работа удобного UI и уверенного владения мыши, на мой взгляд. В форме ответа, к примеру, мне особо не приходится целиться.

Comment: @ИванПшеницын А, вот оно что. Такой юзкейс понятен и имеет право на существование, просто лично мне нечасто бывает нужен: да, я нечасто смотрю долго на большие куски кода на со. Код интересных мне вопросов я разглядываю в студии, для этого полезнее кнопки быстро выделить для вставки. Не особо интересных -- лишь бегло просматриваю по-диагонали. Право, неинтересных гораздо больше.

Comment: Горизонтально тоже надо.

Answer (score 2):

Фрагменты кода предназначены для размещения [минимального, самодостаточного и воспроизводимого примера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), который подразумевает небольшие вставки кода с пояснениями проблемы или решения.

То, что мы наблюдаем в приведенном примере – недостаток вопроса. Согласитесь, с большой вероятностью, нам нет необходимости знать о всех закрытых полях класса, нам не нужны и комментарии.

Реализация подобной функции – поощрение неправильного использования сайта.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вы, несомненно, правы. Тем не менее, подобное использование сайта имеет место быть и от этого никуда не деться. Закрывать вопросы потому что новичок не придумал как сократить код чтобы он влез в какие-то рамки - бессмысленно, как и оставлять их без ответа. И есть два варианта подхода: упереться рогом и сказать, что "это неправильно и будем терпеть, но не прогнемся" или сделать себе удобно. Разумеется, мои слова относятся к ситуации, когда с тем, что это неудобно, согласятся многие из активных пользователей. Иначе это обсуждение не имеет смысла.

Comment: Идеологически, если в вопросе есть излишний код, его стоит удалить. Кто это сделает, не так важно (имеется в виду знатоки, получившие привилегию правки чужих сообщений, или автор вопроса). Цель проекта – собрать базу прикладных решений. После публикации информации на сайте, сообщество ответственно за качество содержимого.